# Operate on data in Google Cloud Storage bucket from Virtual Machine without downloading data to the VM hard drive - .NET

Tags: .net, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

Is there a way to feed a data file stored on a Google Cloud Storage bucket into a Windows command line process operating on a Google Virtual Machine without first downloading the file from the Google Cloud Storage bucket to the Virtual Machine's harddrive?

I have a .NET application that launches a Google Virtual Machine which then downloads data from Google Cloud Storage bucket to the Virtual Machine's hard drive.  The Google Virtual Machine runs another .NET exe which calls a collection of command line applications (one of which is java, but there are others) which use the files downloaded from the cloud as inputs and uploads output data files to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.

The current approach works well for small input files(several MB) downloaded from Google Cloud Storage but the desired input files will be 20-40Gb. I'm spending several hours of Virtual Machine computer time downloading the files from the cloud so the command line applications can operate on local data.  I would like to spend my compute time operating on the data rather than moving it around.

Is there a way to pass a reference or a http link to the data location in the cloud and have the command line applications treat the reference or the http link as the path to a remote hard drive?  That would eliminate the time downloading the files to the VM's local hard drive.

I don't need to alter the input data files, just create new output data files based on the input data files.

I tried passing the http path to the bucket appended with the input file name as the path to the file as a command line arguement, but I received an error.  The path looked something like this:

```
https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/[input file bucket]/[input file name]
```

The error was

> Failed to open file `https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/[input file bucket]/[input file name]`

I feel like treating a Google Cloud Storage bucket as a remote hard drive for reading data should be achievable.

Any examples, follow-up questions or recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: You can create singed urls which can be accessed for a specified period of time without authentication. More information are on this link https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/signurl

Comment: You also can make an API call to access objects in the bucket. The request URIs which you can use can be found on this link  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-uris